# Forcing ssh to a login using a specific user when requst is made to a specific port

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, multiple-users

I want to set up a small thing where friends of mine can `ssh` into my server and join a tiny chatroom. Now I have most of it setup, but I don't know how to make it so that the client username is irrelevant.

Currently, `ssh chat@example.com` works great. However, I would love to be able to shorten it to `ssh example.com`, and and have it use the `chat` account regardless.

There is no other users that are available on this sshd service, so the config is *just* for this chat thing. I'm having trouble finding any information on this under the multitude of `.ssh/config` tutorials so any help would be appreciated.